# How validate data from post in restful api

Tags: php, symfony, model-view-controller, code-structure, symfony-validator

I need to validate some data before insert into the database, for that i create a little service that return invalid fields from an entity. It works ok when validating single entities.

```
class EntityValidator
{
    protected $validator;

    public function __construct(ValidatorInterface $validator)
    {
        $this->validator = $validator;
    }

    public function validate($entity)
    {
        $errors = $this->validator->validate($entity);
        $response = null;
        if ($errors->count()) {
            foreach ($errors as $error) {
                $response[$error->getPropertyPath()] = $error->getMessage();
            }
        }

        return $response;
    }
}
```

But I have been struggling to validate more complex problems for example:
This is a restful api endpoint that receives a json with user_id and percentage in the body of the post, it will validate the entity to see if it's right as mapped with symfony validator constraints.

```
public function create(Request $request, EntityValidator $entityValidator)
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    $entityExample = new EntityExample();
    $entityExample
         ->setUserId($data['user_id'])
         ->setPercentage($data['percentage'])
    ;
    $errors = $entityValidator->validate($entityExample);
    // .. do other things ..
    return new JsonResponse($errors);    
}
```

But lets say that I receive an array of data and I going to insert many row at a time and there's a business logic that say "the sum of percentage of a user need to be 100"

```
public function create(Request $request, EntityValidator $entityValidator)
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), true);
    $totalPercentage = 0;
    foreach ($data as $element) {
         $entityExample = new EntityExample();
         $entityExample
             ->setUserId($element['user_id'])
             ->setPercentage($element['percentage'])
         ;
         $totalPercentage += $element['percentage'];
    }
    $errors = $entityValidator->validate($entityExample);
    if ($totalPecentage != 100) {
        $errors[] = 'Sum of percentage must be 100';
    }
    // .. do other things ..
    return new JsonResponse($errors);    
}
```

It seems wrong keep this kind of business logic inside controller but I don't know where put it, should I create a service just for that? then every endpoint that has more complex validation will be create a new service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Create a model representation of your JSON request payload. A model with public properties and nothing else. e.g. Let's say model is called `Sale`.
2. Create a custom [Validation Constraint](https://symfony.com/doc/current/validation/custom_constraint.html) which would be wired with `Sale` model. In this validation class you would iterate through `Sale.percentage` property and run your validation logic.
3. In your controller, you call serializer component and validator component to validate the request.

Full examples for each points above:

1. Both links below have model examples but if you want more examples just do ctrl+f `json` in this page http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/posts/symfony
2. [Class level custom assert validation constraint in symfony](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/tm05/class-level-custom-assert-validation-constraint-in-symfony)
3. [A simple way of handling request, response and exceptions in Symfony API](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/k59j/a-simple-way-of-handling-request-response-and-exceptions-in-symfony-api). Copy and do not touch `AbstractController`. Do what `UserController::create` does for your own controller. He is using `$this->data` for demonstration purposes in same controller but you should pass it to a service and process it there.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I need. Liked the site, a lot of useful information.